# No module named 'globals'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a folder that has a Django Framework in it.
I try to call files that are outside of this folder but I get the following error:
No module named 'globals'

This path folder: api_yahoo_finance/yahoo/api_yahoo/views
And in the views file, I try to use the file that exists outside this folder. (Outside of api_yahoo)

I tried to read on the internet and understand what the problem is, I saw comments that said to add a **init** file, I added it but it didn't help.

**

- It is important to note, the package is a local package, I created
  it.

**

Answer (score 0):

According to the Django documentation, your project directory should be like this:

```
mysite/
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        asgi.py
        wsgi.py
    first_app/
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    venv/
    manage.py
```

You should install your packages in your virtual environment.
See more in Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Hi dude, my package is a local package, without pip install
I created the package.